# Destruct Run Time error

Tags: c++

I have written a linkelist code with a function append a linked list to another but when the destructer called it cause run time error

this is the code

```
class doublelist
{
private :
    doublelist *L;
    doublelist *next;
    double x;
public:
    doublelist(double x[], int size)
    {
        if (!x)return;
        L = new doublelist();
        L->x = x[0];
        L->next = NULL;
        doublelist *temp = L;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            temp->next = new doublelist();
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->x = x[i];
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    ~doublelist()
    {
        doublelist *temp = L;
        while (temp)
        {
            delete temp;
            cout << temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            temp = L;
        }
    }
};
void main()
{
    double a[] = { 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7 };
    doublelist me(a, 6);
    double b[] = { 10, 213, 4 };
    me.append(doublelist(b, 3));
    me.print();
    system("pause");
}
```

oh im sorry .. i tried to fix the code but i couldn't here is the destructer

```
~doublelist()
{
    doublelist *temp = L;
    while (temp)
    {
        L = L->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = L;
    }
}
```

Comment: `delete temp;  cout << temp;` That can't be good.

Comment: You've got a use after free in the destructor. You cant use something after youve deleted it.

Comment: oh im sorry .. i tried to fix the code but i couldn't here is the destructer ~doublelist(){ doublelist*temp = L; while (temp){ L = L->next; delete temp; temp = L; } }

Answer (score 4):

Look at this code in your destructor:

```
delete temp;       // calling delete 
cout << temp;
temp = temp->next; // using a pointer that has been deleted.
```

Calling `delete` is the last (safe) thing you can do with a pointer.

Comment: oh im sorry .. i tried to fix the code but i couldn't 

here is the destructer 
~doublelist(){
  doublelist*temp = L;
  while (temp){
   L = L->next;
   delete temp;
   temp = L;
  }
 }

Comment: move `doublelist*temp = L` inside the loop.

Comment: again didn't work! ..

Comment: well the best to find out is to debug it. Since you didn't post the whole code, it could be anything. Btw, `main` is type `int` *not* `void`.

Comment: same thing .. i can post all the code with all functions if you want..

Comment: well just compile the code with debug info and run the debugger. Step by step, you'll see what causes the failure.

Comment: Omg!! does the destuctor called in the begining ?!?!?!? because i tried to put cout<<"hi" in it; the program printed hi then printed then called the print function!!